# Is there a simple way to prove that $f$ is holomorphic implies $f\in C^1(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a simple way to prove that $f$ is holomorphic implies $f\in C^1(\mathbb{C})$? $f\in C^1(\mathbb{C})$ means that its derivative is continuous. Please try to work out without the average theorem.

I know it is a classical proposition of complex analysis but the common proofs are based on the average theorem:
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\mathrm{d}\zeta.$$Here $C$ is a closed curve in simple connected area $\Omega$ and $z$ is inside $C$.

In the process of trying to prove the average theorem, I got the proof of $f\in C^1(\mathbb{C})$. So I came up with the question.

Comment: There is no “simple” proof of this fact. This is an ‘automatic regularity’ theorem, and these are in general not easy. Here, one is exploiting something fundamental about complex multiplication. Another perspective is that the Cauchy-Riemann are a set of elliptic PDEs, and one has very general elliptic regularity theorems. But again there is no ‘simple’ proof of this fact. That’s why one goes through the hurdles using Goursat’s lemma and Cauchy’s integral formula etc.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Derivative exists everywhere.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks, I think I'm getting a sense of the complexity.

Comment: I'm trying to find a proof of the average theorem based on Green formula, which needs the continuity of $f'$.@AnneBauval

Comment: If a function is holomorphic in the entire plane then it is represented by the power series $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ which is convergent uniformly on bounded sets. Then it is relatively easy to show that $f'(z)=\sum na_nz^{n-1}$ as this new series is also almost uniformly convergent.

Comment: @AnneBauval That's right. First one should show that the function is analytic, which is pretty easy once we have the Cauchy theorem mentioned in OP, by expanding $(\zeta-z)^{-1}$ into power series. Or directly prove that the derivative is represented by the integral of $f(\zeta)(\zeta-z)^{-2}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Do you think that the formula $(1-q)^{-1}=\sum q^n$ is hard ? That's all you need to prove analycity.

Comment: @AnneBauval It's hard to avoid the Cauchy theorem. I do not see an easy way to get continuity of the derivative or partial derivatives of the real and imaginary part. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc No I haven't. I appreciate peek-a-boo's comment.